# Conditional belongs_to: only comments for post with published flag set TRUE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to

I'd like to grab only certain comments for a post: those that have a published boolean set TRUE.

Right now, I simply call a `@post.comments.all` on the Post show action.

Creating a method (published_comments) in the Post.rb model feels ugly to me; I have the feeling such code belongs in the Comment.rb model. But then I am not sure how to call if from within a Post object.

Moreover, I really like the options that `belongs_to` offers me, such as the counter_cache or eager loading.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole bunch of ways to deal with this kind of thing. One option is to define it as a condition in the `has_many` association in the `Post` model, but it sounds like you don't like this approach:

```
class Post
  has_many :comments, :conditions => { :published => true }
end
```

Another option is to set the `default_scope` in the Comment model:

```
class Comment
  default_scope where(:published => true)
end
```

Or, you could create a scope in comment and call `@post.comments.published.all`:

```
class Comment
  scope :published, where(:published => true)
end
```

Comment: The default_scope is exactly what I needed here. Thanks.

Comment: Weird, though. default_scope where(:published => true) results in a strange query; seems like the sqlite connector interpretes the boolean wrong: `... WHERE ("comments"."published" = 't') ...`